# How to add code based on count of something when i dont know the exact count

Tags: python, list

I´m trying to make a snake game without graphics to train with lists. Game pretty much works but I need to find a way how to make the snake longer when he eats food. Well I know how to do it manually, write the same thing 100 times with different numbers and use `if`, but how to automate it? I know there is some better way to code this game, but is it possible to do it with this and just change something? I tried to do it with for x in range, but didn´t work out, maybe I did it wrong I don´t know.

```py
def snake():
    y = 5 #starting point on Y axis
    x = 9 #starting point on X axis
    length = 10 #length of the map
    width = 10 #width of the map
    food = [(2, 3), (4, 5)] #coordinates of food
    coordinates = [(y, x)] #where head of the snake currently is
    food2 = [(y, x)] #current position + position of food
    fcount = 0 #number of ate food
    erase = 0
    way = 1

    while way != "stop":
        way = input("Choose your way, use wasd: ")
        if way == "s":
            y = y + 1
        elif way == "w":
            y = y - 1
        elif way == "d":
            x = x + 1
        elif way == "a":
            x = x - 1


        coordinates.append([(y, x)])
        
        food2.append((y, x))

        if y < 0:
            raise ValueError("This doesn´t work")
        elif x < 0:
            raise ValueError("This doesnt´t work")
        
        if food2[-1] in food:
            fcount = fcount + 1



        for g in range(length):
            
            for z in range(width):
                position = (g, z)

                
                    
                if position in coordinates[-1]:
                    print("x", end = " ")
                elif position in coordinates[-2]: #I need to make something like this for all the food therecould be
                    if fcount > 0:
                        print("x", end = " ")
                        erase = erase + 1
                    else:
                        print(".", end = " ")

                elif position in food:
                    print("?", end = " ")
                else:
                    print(".", end = " ")
                

                while erase == 1:
                    if fcount == 1:
                        food.remove(food2[-1])
                        erase = erase + 1
                        break
                    break
                    
            print()

    print(fcount)

print(snake())
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some more details. _"I tried to do it ... but it didn't work"_: what happened? How did its behavior differ from what you expected? What _specifically_ is the problem here? It usually helps to draw a flowchart detailing the steps you would take to solve the problem if _you_ were the computer, and then writing code that instructs the computer to take those steps.

Comment: Well I don´t think it does matter what it did because I´m asking for a way how to do it, I don´t know if for x in range is the right thing to make it work. The problem is said in the question, how to change the code to make it grow after the snake eats, but to "automate" the part elif position in coordinates[-2], so I don´t have to do elif on every number of food eaten.  @PranavHosangadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other problems that I see, but if you only want to find a way to grow a snake in, as you say, 'auotomatic' mode, you can try calling `print('x')` when `position in coordinates[-1-fcount:]`.

I have slightly modified your code to show how this can be done. However, as I said, I see other problems, and when someone tries to solve them, it may turn out that the way to grow a snake can be done differently.

```
def snake():
    y = 5 #starting point on Y axis
    x = 9 #starting point on X axis
    length = 10 #length of the map
    width = 10 #width of the map
    food = [(2, 3), (4, 5)] #coordinates of food
    coordinates = [(y, x)] #where head of the snake currently is
    fcount = 0 #number of ate food
    way = 1

    while way != "stop":
        way = input("Choose your way, use wasd: ")
        if way == "s":
            y = y + 1
        elif way == "w":
            y = y - 1
        elif way == "d":
            x = x + 1
        elif way == "a":
            x = x - 1

        coordinates.append((y, x))
                
        if (y,x) in food:
            fcount = fcount + 1
            food.remove((y,x))
            
        for g in range(length):
            for z in range(width):
                position = (g, z)
                if position in coordinates[-1-fcount:]:
                    print("x", end = " ")
                elif position in food:
                    print("?", end = " ")
                else:
                    print(".", end = " ")                    
            print()


snake()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Works just how I wanted. This solution didn´t cross my mind... Thank you